# In airflow, is there a good way to call another dag's task?

Tags: airflow

I've got dag_prime and dag_tertiary.

- `dag_prime`: Scans through a directory and intends to call dag_tertiary
  on each one.  Currently a PythonOperator.
- `dag_tertiary`: Scans through the directory passed to it and does (possibly time-intensive) calculations on the contents thereof.

I can call the secondary one from a system call from the python operator, but i feel like there's got to be a better way.  I'd also like to consider queuing the dag_tertiary calls, if there's a simple way to do that.  Is there a better way than using system calls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun` for calling one DAG from another.

The details can be found in operator [trigger_dagrun Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#module-airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun).

Following post gives a good example of using this operator:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/airflow-lesson-1-triggerdagrunoperator-siddharth-anand

Comment: Can this be done in a loop though?  I've seen the triggerdagrunoperator and from what i can tell it does what the name says - triggers a (single) dag run.  Is there a way to trigger many of those in a loop?

Comment: You can place it in a loop and trigger through it as many times as you want. I have used dynamic task creation in a DAG using for loop for my use cases (with different operators but it should be the same with this operator as well).

Comment: Can some parameters be passed from one dag to other dag while calling?

if so, how to access those passed parameters in the triggered dag?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TriggerDagRunOperator` from `airflow.operators.dagrun_operator` and pass the other DAG name to `triger_dag_id` parameter.

Follow Airflow updated documentation [dag_run_operator Airflow Documentation](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.6/_api/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator/index.html)