# Trigger a task when another finished with success

Tags: airflow

My use-case is as follows:

- `Task A` is generating `dataset` using some input raw data
- `Task B` is running some code using `dataset` as input
- `Task C` is running some other code using `dataset` as input

The three tasks are scheduled to run daily, and `Task B` and `Task C` are scheduled to run *enough time* after `Task A`, and simply fail if the input dataset has not been generated for some reason.

As a first improvement I added an `ExternalTaskSensor` in both `Task B` and `Task C`, but this just avoids to run them if `Task A` did not yet finished or failed.

However, `ExternalTaskSensor` seems not to be working fine with *backfilling* (it is pretty fragile as it relies on *execution date* only, plus if `Task A` is run again, `Task B` and `Task C` won't know).

**Solution 1 (not applicable):**
I have seen this SO's question: [In airflow, is there a good way to call another dag's task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271532/in-airflow-is-there-a-good-way-to-call-another-dags-task)

This is not ideal for me because I'd like to keep `Task A` *unaware* of the dependent tasks, and handle the logic in `Task B` and `Task C` (or externally). Reason is that other tasks consuming the output of `Task A` will be added in the future (from different teams across the organization), and it's not desirable to update `Task A` each time.

**Summary**
I'd like to trigger `Task B` and `Task C` if and only if `Task A` has been executed with success (independently if it has been scheduled or triggered manually), without modifying `Task A` to achieve that.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by *keep Task A unaware of the dependent tasks*? I can't understand why task B and task C can't be downstream tasks depending on task A. Or why task B and task C can't be moved to a separate DAG triggered from first DAG with only task A.

Comment: The point is that I'd like to add many more tasks depending on `Task A` in the future, but I'd like to have them *register* somehow, rather than update `Task A` all the time. Rationale is that `Task A` and the consuming tasks are likely to be handled by different teams, so the effort should be in the consumer side if possible. For `Task B` and `Task C` to be downstreams of `Task A`, they have to be inside the same DAG, right? I'd avoid that too, if possible, for the same reason.

Comment: I see what you mean. You will be developing `task A` which returns some results. Then other developers will be using output from your task to perform their own tasks (Lets say `task B` and `task C`). You don't want to modify the task A code every time someone wants to use `task A`.

Comment: I will update the question to make it more explicit, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To suit your scenario, the only concept I can think of is SubDags. (Refer to WARNING before you implement)

`SubDagOperator` allows you to attach a set of tasks to your `task A`. Refer to code below.

```
dag = DAG('parent_dag', description='Parent',
          schedule_interval='@daily',
          start_date=datetime.now())

task_a = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task_a')

subdag_task = SubDag(task_id='load_tasks',
    subdag=load_subdag('parent_dag', 'dependent_tasks'),
    dag=dag)

task_a >> subdag_task
```

Now in a separate file you define your `load_subdag` function.

```
def load_subdag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name):
    dag_subdag = DAG(
        dag_id='{0}.{1}'.format(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
        schedule_interval="@daily",
    )
    with dag_subdag:
        task_b = DummyOperator(
            task_id='load_subdag_task_b',
            dag=dag_subdag)

       task_c = DummyOperator(
            task_id='load_subdag_task_c',
            dag=dag_subdag)

    return dag_subdag
```

WARNING (In Red and bold): SubDag tasks occupy slots in your worker like maggots. Please understand the caveats completely before you jump into this. [AIRFLOW-74](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-74) gives a picture of how bad it can be. It is outright rejected by many developers for the same reason.