# How can I run all all neccessary DAGs / Do I need ExternalTaskSensor?

Tags: airflow

is it possible to run two dags at another time with the externalTaskSensor?

I have two DAGs. 
DAG A runs every two hours

- 10 a.m. (successful)
- 12a.m. (failed)
- 2 p.m. (successful)

Dag B is depended on DAG A. DAG B waits for DAG A at 12 a.m and fails, because DAG A failed. But since DAG A was successful at 2 p.m., Dag B should suppose to run.

How can you implement this? With an ExternalTaskSensor?

I just have a small dummy, to try to understand it.

```
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.timezone import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import airflow 

source_dag = DAG(
    dag_id='sensor_dag_source',
    start_date = datetime(2020, 1, 20),
    schedule_interval='* * * * *'
)

first_task = DummyOperator(task_id='first_task', dag=source_dag)

target_dag = DAG(
    dag_id='sensor_dag_target',
    start_date = datetime(2020, 1, 20),
    schedule_interval='* * * * *'   
)

task_sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
    dag=target_dag,
    task_id='dag_sensor_source_sensor',
    retries=100,
    retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=30),
    mode='reschedule',
    external_dag_id='sensor_dag_source',
    external_task_id='first_task'
)

first_task = DummyOperator(task_id='first_task', dag=target_dag)

task_sensor >> first_task
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try and use TriggerDagRunOperator and trigger DAG B from DAG A

here is a full answer-
[In airflow, is there a good way to call another dag's task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271532/in-airflow-is-there-a-good-way-to-call-another-dags-task)

there is another good post about it-

[Wiring top-level DAGs together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325525/wiring-top-level-dags-together)